# Get content from a block

Tags: bolt-cms

I´m currently building a website with Bolt as a CMS. But right now I´m struggling with getting the content out of a block. My contenttypes.yml:

```
blocks:
    name: Blocks
    singular_name: Block
    fields:
        title:
            type: text
            class: large
            group: "Block"
        slug:
            type: slug
            uses: [ title ]
        text-one:
            type: text
            label: Tekst 1
            group: content
        text-two:
            type: text
            label: Tekst 2
            group: content
        text-three:
            type: text
            label: Tekst 3
            group: content
        text-four:
            type: text
            label: Tekst 4
            group: content
        text-five:
            type: text
            label: Tekst 5
            group: content
        text-six:
            type: text
            label: Tekst 6
            group: content
```

My Twig code:

```
{% setcontent block_cta = "block/cta-nl" %}
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just posted answer on your question hope it helps. but eeh btw ` uses: [ title ]` sould just be ` uses: title `

Answer (score 0):

Hello your doing it a little bit wrong. if you want to get the value's out of an content type you should try this

`{% setcontent name = "blocks" %}`

you should call uppon the content type.

if you want to test what this gives back: `{{ dump(test) }}`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You solution doesn't work, the result is still empty.

Comment: i had a brainfart. the "name" is the name of the content. it should be {{ dump(name) }}

Comment: that should return something. i tested it this time.